# Consequences of the Euler characteristic vanishing mod p

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth compact connected manifold. If $\chi(M)=0$, the unit tangent bundle $S(TM) \rightarrow M$ has a section. Is there anything that can be said if $\chi(M)$ is congruent to $0$ mod $p$ for some number $p$? For example, is there a section of the bundle of spectra formed by fiberwise smashing the unit tangent bundle with $H\mathbf{Z/p}$? If this is not true, is there some other homotopy theoretic sense in which one can say that a ``nowhere-vanishing vector field exists mod $p$’’ if the Euler characteristic vanishes mod $p$?

Comment: There should be cohomological consequences, e.g. the mod $p$ Gysin sequence will split up into short exact sequences.